# multivariable for loop in gnu make (like in bmake)

Tags: loops, for-loop, makefile

bmake gives you the ability to use very useful for loop

```
LIST= \
  s1 t1 \
  s2 t2 \
  s3 t3

all:
.for s t in ${LIST}
    @echo ${s} ${t}
.endfor
```

effect will be:

```
# bmake
s1 t1
s2 t2
s3 t3
```

Is it possible to do something like this in gnu make?
thx

Answer (score 3):

No.  But you can do it differently, something like:

```
LIST = s1:t1 s2:t2 s3:t3

all: ; $(foreach L,$(LIST),echo $(subst :, ,$L) ;)
```

Choose a different delimiter if your list entries might have `:` in them.